# D3 Each Method Not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm trying to create a bar graph with d3 and DOM elements, rather than SVG graphics. I'm having trouble understanding the each method.

I have data that looks like this:

```
data = [
  {
    month: "Aug",
    balances: [
      {
        date: "2015-08-13",
        balance: 500.00
      },
      {
        date: "2015-08-14",
        balance: 480.00
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    month: "Sep",
    balances: [
      {
        date: "2015-09-13",
        balance: 500.00
      },
      {
        date: "2015-09-14",
        balance: 480.00
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

I need to create a specific markup layout where each month is contained in it's own `<div class="graph-month"></div>`. I'm then trying to fill each `.graph-month` with div's that represent bars of data.

The problem is, my bars are getting added to the body, not the individual `.graph-month` divs. When I debug this code, d3.select(this) inside of the each method correctly returns the current "graph-month" d3 selection, but the append statement ends up appending to the page body.

This is inside an Angular directive, so element[0] is the containing directive.

```
var container = d3.select(element[0]);
container.selectAll('div')
  .data(data).enter()
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', "graph-month")
  .attr("data-month", function(d){ return d.month })
  .each(function(d,i){
    // draw the bar background and foreground
    d3.select(this) //should be selecting the current graph-month
      .data(d.balances).enter() //should be setting the data to dailyBalances
      .append('div')
      .attr('class', "graph-bar-background")
      .append('div')
      .attr('class', "graph-bar")
      .text(function(d){ return d.balance; }
   })
   .append('h5').text(function(d){
     return d.month;
   });
```

My starting markup looks like this (minus all the includes, etc)

```
<html>
  <body>
    <bar-graph data="myData"></bar-graph>
  </body>
</html>
```

My ending markup looks like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <bar-graph data="myData">
      <div class="graph-month" data-month="Aug">
        <h5>Aug</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="graph-month" data-month="Sep">
        <h5>Sep</h5>
      </div>
    </bar-graph>
  </body>
  <div class="graph-bar-background">
    <div class="graph-bar">500.00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="graph-bar-background">
    <div class="graph-bar">480.00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="graph-bar-background">
    <div class="graph-bar">500.00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="graph-bar-background">
    <div class="graph-bar">480.00</div>
  </div>
</html>
```

The result I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <bar-graph data="myData">
      <div class="graph-month" data-month="Aug">
        <div class="graph-bar-background">
          <div class="graph-bar">500.00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="graph-bar-background">
          <div class="graph-bar">480.00</div>
        </div>
        <h5>Aug</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="graph-month" data-month="Sep">
        <div class="graph-bar-background">
          <div class="graph-bar">500.00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="graph-bar-background">
          <div class="graph-bar">480.00</div>
        </div>
        <h5>Sep</h5>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the selectAll in the `each` function

```
.each(function(d,i){
    // draw the bar background and foreground
    d3.select(this) //should be selecting the current graph-month
        .selectAll('.graph-bar-background')
        .data(d.balances).enter() //should be setting the data to dailyBalances
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', "graph-bar-background")
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', "graph-bar")
        .text(function (d) { return d.balance; });
})
```

The new line is `.selectAll('.graph-bar-background')` indicates the DOM collection you need d.balances to map to.

Comment: I used `.selectAll('div')` and that worked just as well. Thanks!